# DevOps "Ng Build" do not create .js files correclty

Tags: angular, build, devops

When in the development environment I build my Angular project with the command `ng build --prod --aot` and all hashed .js files are created nicely to /dist folder:

```
main.7e47ed28ca0334b01383.js (602kb)
polyfills.54a6c8e7e6863aa90225.js (59kb)
runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (2kb)
scripts.c79426ad610cbf775bf5.js (360kb)
```

But in DevOps I use the same command:
/dist folder root is empty. But there is subfolder dist/out-tsc. And there I can find Main.js (2kb) some other "almost empty .js file"

When I debug DevOps I can see that hashed files are creted:
[DevOps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPd04.png)
But when build is ready and artifact is created I can find only empty dist folder with out-tsc folder.

What might cause this?

PS I have row:
"outDir": "dist/out-tsc",

at tsconfig.json. But changiong it to  "outDir": "dist", just cause empty .js files to /dist folder. Also removing  "outDir": "dist/out-tsc", do not help.

Comment: What do you mean by "in devOps"? Also what's in your `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Ahh sorry . I mean DevOps build server.